# Installing Ubuntu in VM with Vagrant without automatically installing GNOME?

Tags: virtualbox, mate

I'm setting up a vagrant script on my MacBook Pro to set up an Ubuntu Focal LTS VM. I've provisioned it to install [Mate DE](https://ubuntu-mate.org), but when I set it up, it's automatically installing GNOME and overwriting Mate. I know Mate is based off of GNOME 2, but that doesn't seem to be the reason as previously today, the mate provision was fine (I've been tweaking things and doing `vagrant up` and `vagrant destroy` on and off all day).

My Vagrantfile is installing `config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"` and my provision file can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/0pT1wF5z)

Thank you folks

Comment: Silly question, but why not start with an Ubuntu MATE image rather than stock Ubuntu? 

Comment: @matigo I can't find any based off of 20.04 LTS that still works with a proper mate. I've just tried https://app.vagrantup.com/chenhan/boxes/ubuntu-mate-desktop-20.04 and it still boots into a broken gnome de. I've also tried doing this: https://superuser.com/a/686001 and nothing

Comment: I would recommend to replace line 9 with `apt-get install -y ubuntu-mate-desktop^` . Note `^` at the end, it means task package, so MATE will be installed exactly as in Ubuntu MATE. And please do not change system version of the Python, comment out  lines 20-26. It may break the whole system.

Comment: @N0rbert I managed to figure out the MATE install thing. But why don't I want to change the python version? Is there not a way to make `python3` launch py310 then?